# Required field validator Submit issue

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a web form (say form 1) created for a small dine-in with a submit button.
The fields to be validated are Name (textbox) gender(radio button) and so on.
below this form on the same page is a feedback form (say form 2) having two fields: name(textbox) and feedback(text area).
The feedback form has a submit button.

PROBLEM: When submit button of feedback form is clicked feedback is not submitted due to the required fields in form 1 are not filled in.

I want the feedback to be submitted. Please help.

image of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/97tuva03bl33xur/form.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same `ValidationGroup` for each form.

Comment: second form has no validation

Comment: but you have to specify first forms validationgroup.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ValidationGroup` use this code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAreaName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
          ControlToValidate="TxtAreaName" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="a"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="a" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Yes things worked ! Thanks . Can u tell the reason ? i had kept it blank at first .